# Excel Transpose and Concatenate Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have my data table like this in excel.

Each Master Code group together my Clients ID.

```
Master Code        Client ID
1                  172371;255712
1                  172371;C00322
2                  172408;287222;C00413
2                  172408;287222
3                  172931;265681;C01791
3                  172931;265681
3                  173131;267217;C02187
```

I would like to return the results like this in the column 'Merge all'. I only need the first row of the Master Code which contains already all the clients ID. But if the row Master Code is duplicate like in the example, it wont matters.

```
Master Code     Client ID                Merge all
1           172371;255712              172371;255712;C00322
1           172371;C00322              172371;255712;C00322
2           172408;287222;C00413       172408;287222;C00413
2           172408;287222              172408;287222;C00413
3           172931;265681;C01791       172931;265681;C01791;267217;173131
3           172931;265681              172931;265681;C01791;267217;173131
3           173131;267217;C02187       172931;265681;C01791;267217;173131
```

Is there any ways I can achieve this in excel? Is it actually possible to get done?

Comment: What version of Excel?  If you have Windows O365, you can do this with formulas. Otherwise, VBA or Power Query would provide an easier solution.  Also, please explain the results of `Merge All` for `Master Code 3`.  You are only returning two of the codes from the last line, and in reverse order of their entry.

Comment: Hi @Ron Rosenfeld, yes I have windows O365. The returning order dosent matters here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: But that does not explain why you are not returning `C02187` for code `3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your Merge All column is in error by not showing `C02187` for `Master Code 3`, then the following formula returns desired results.

Note that I have made the data range a `Table` and am using structured references. I think it is more efficient (dynamic named ranges) and easier to understand.  But you could change it to regular references if you prefer.

*The only issue with this method is that, if any of your Client ID's are all digits and start with zero(s), leading zeros will be dropped. If that might be an issue, Power Query is an alternate solution*

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,FILTER([Client ID],[Master Code]=[@[Master Code]])),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

[image]

- `FILTER` returns only the `Client ID` for the matching `Master Code`
- `SUBSTITUTE` and the inner `TEXTJOIN` create an XML with each ID in the filtered table being a separate node.
- `FILTERXML` extracts each node separately.
- `UNIQUE` removes the duplicates (although this could be done with the `xPath` argument instead, for those that don't have `UNIQUE`.
- The outer `TEXTJOIN` puts it back together in a semicolon separated fashion.